# What properties are conserved when elementary particles react with one another?

Tags: particle-physics, conservation-laws, standard-model, subatomic

I read that when two elementary particles, which are subatomic particles, combine with each other the charge, lepton number, strangness and Baryon number must be preserved. Is there any other property that must be preserved?

Also, is there are quarks involved in such reactions, is there such a property associated with the "color" of the quark?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interactions conserve four-momentum and electrostatic charge. Flavor counts such as strangeness are conserved, except in weak interactions. There are three kinds of lepton number; neutrino oscillation conserves their sum $L$, but not the three numbers individually. Interactions also conserve $B-L$ (probably; see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_%E2%88%92_L)), with $B$ the baryon number. Usually $B,\,L$ are separately conserved, although some non-perturbative interactions are exceptions; see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baryon_number#Conservation) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baryogenesis#GUT_Baryogenesis_under_Sakharov_conditions).